# Check for duplicate names in text file and change them C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am trying to write to a file with around 20 fields. That part works. The first field needs to be unique (can't have duplicates). I cannot figure out how to take only the first field(column) and compare it to the rest in that column. Also I am not sure how to get the variable from the file. The field is a combination of the first and last name. That works just fine but I need to run through the `userName` and compare it to the rest of them. If another one is the exact same, I need a number added to one of them.

This is what I started but I am not sure now to continue:

```
class userName
{
    public string Name(string userName)
    {
        string initialUserName 
        string tempUserName = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

This is how I create the user name:

```
username = firstName.Substring(0, 4) + lastName.Substring(0, 4);
```

Comment: You say you are using Streamwriter to write your file yet I can't seem to find it in your code

Comment: does it need to be a text file? people could edit it easily by hand then.. add dups etc.. how are you writing it - what is its purpose

Comment: @Gianlucca I wanted to try to uses StreamWriter but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Then update your question to "How to use StreamWriter". You have a misleading title

Comment: @BugFinder yes it does. Well I have an original file that is not in the correct format or layout. I need to rearrange the fields and do some formatting to certain fields. The user name being one of them. I haven't had any issues with any of the other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of how you are writing these "fields," im assuming a single line (row) of your file contains all 20 fields. Hopefully you have delimited each of these fields. You should be able to get all the variables in the first column by reading the lines of the file, one at a time, and using the [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-parse-strings-using-string-split) method to get a string array containing all of your 20 fields. Simply compare the first array member to your new value, if its equal then append a number to the new string, continue this until all rows are parsed.

Comment: basically each line is a persons name and their information. I read the contents of the original file, format what needs to be, and then write to a new text file.

Comment: @imsohappy So giving what you just said, my above stated answer should suffice. Just a tip or two: if you know the first field is what you are comparing, you could also use string.substring(0, string.firstindexof([your delimiter])), I have not bench-marked, so I cannot guarantee this would be more optimal, but its another idea. Also (unless there is a specific need for rewriting the entire file) consider appending the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help. Use streamreader and streamwriter to read and write the text file. Create hashtable store the column read value in it. If you find same content just don't write it.